# Sending UTF-8 web page from python thru apache - blank?

Tags: apache

OSX 10.6, apache2, python 2.6

ok, basically, I have a UTF-8 file, no BOM, containing a web page, foo.html. If it's saved as ascii, no extended Unicode chars, I can open it, send a header, print the file, and it shows up in a web browser just fine when I hit my URL showpag.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs
fh = codecs.open('foo.html',encoding='utf-8')
pag = fh.read()
fh.close()
print u'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'
print u''
print pag
```

However, if I embed actual unicode in the foo.html (say, a chinese string), then safari (and chrome, and omniweb, etc., basically anything using webkit I think) displays a blank page with no content. When I say blank, I mean white, nothing there, "display source" returns nothing as well. It would appear that apache refuses to send the data at all.

foo.html is very basic:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Test Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
English and UNICODE-CHINESE-CHARACTERS
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I've tried:

- turning off gzip output in apache conf
- changing the DefaultType to none
- using sys.stdout.write(pag)
- With and without the META tag for content type
- With and without a content-length header

...none of these changes the results.

I carefully restart web services with each change to apache's conf.

Delete the unicode chars in foo.html, and it works. Put them in, apache sends a blank page.

The same thing happens if I don't read the file, but instead, generate output right from python:

```
x = u'CHINESE-UNICODE-CHARS'
print x
```

...that makes a blank page, while this:

```
x = u'ENGLISH-UNICODE-CHARS' # ascii, but in unicode string
print x
```

...works just fine (with all the same headers, etc.)

Running the python script from the shell returns the web page in both cases, as expected: The shell displays the unicode characters in the right place and so on. Likewise, if I have apache serve the page directly, the unicode works fine.

It's only when output goes from python through Apache that I get this blank, no-content page. I suspect the stream from python to apache is compromised when 16-bit characters are in use, but I'm at a loss how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is:

```
print pag.encode('utf-8')
```

...the stream between Python and Apache was defaulting to ASCII, so I got nothing.